Does using quotes around an informal word make it acceptable in academic writing?

Riding stunts such as "wheelie," "stoppie," or "drifting" are considered reckless driving when performed on public streets.

All three words are rather informal/slang, and I'm afraid that they are not suitable for academic writing. Are they? Should I use quotes as seen above to mark that they are informal/slang, hence making them usable in academic writing?

I’m voting to close this question because this is about writing style, not about English Language

Those are the informal names for the stunts.   That is what the quotation marks signal.

If you were concerned that some readers might not know what the names referred to, you wouldn't say "such as" but "known as" or "known on the street as". Perhaps adding "among others". You could add a description of each, for any readers unfamiliar with the names.

I voted to close because the question asks for an opinon on acceptability.

@ColinFine I disagree in this instance. As far as I can tell, we haven't explicitly said that style questions are off-topic, even if the answer is usually "Can't say; consult your style guide." But this one is generic enough that I think there can be an on-topic answer.

All three words are perfectly acceptable in a "academic" essay.  They are the technical terms used in riding,  They are not in any sense informal. In fact the opposite, they are the formal technical language of a particular subculture.

This would work better on Writets.SE.

When I was 10 years old, I was "popping wheelies" on my bike.  That's what the kids called these stunts.  They're not "technical" terms -- no more than a "noogie" is.

If you need to use a word from the jargon of a particular activity which has a specific definition within that activity, by all means use it. The quotation marks show, not so much that it is 'informal', but that it has a special meaning in this context.
(I don't know what drifting is in the context of cycling, but it also has a meaning in standard English!)

I presume that drifting here relates to motorsport.

It's OK to use jargon or slang in academic writing, but you should define what those words mean, in context, somewhere in the document. Depending on the type and style this could be in line parenthesis, a numbered footnote on the page or in an appendix, or even a glossary if there are a lot of such words. This applies both to normal English words used with a special / unusual meaning (such as "drifting") and jargon words with no normal usage (such as "stoppie").

This would be absolutely true in an academic essay at an Anglo-speaking university or any higher education level but in a 150-200 word English language essay, such as IELTS, providing a definition for each slang term would rob valuable space and time. There's no need, using speech marks is sufficient to tell the examiner that these words are jargon.

@Mari-LouA Agreed, but the OP does say "academic writing" which I took to be some type of paper, dissertation or book, not (with all due respect to IELTS) an English language exam answer.

In a level B2 or C1 English language exam, a candidate is tested on two writing styles: informal and formal, the latter is often an "academic" essay. I just wanted to reassure future English exam candidates that explaining slang or jargon in formal writing is not always necessary.

Since anything can be studied academically, including things that are socially informal or offensive, academic writing might need to talk about words or usages that it wouldn't actually use. There are entire books that trace the history and sociology of a single word so offensive that casual public use would get someone fired. And you give a great example of a case that might be inoffensive but colloquial, addressing slang terms in formal writing. Yes, using such terms is not only acceptable, but the best choice when there is no easy formal equivalent. For instance, if you need to say "Operating this machinery while drunk is prohibited," then "drunk" is fine and there's no need to use colloquialisms like "hammered" or "shitfaced." But there's no easy formal equivalent for "wheelie," let alone things like "ghost riding the whip," so it's best to use these terms when discussing them. As Peter suggested, it's best to also explain them when they're not common knowledge. If you're going to use a phrase repeatedly within a short section, it might be best to use quotes only on the first instance. After introducing and explaining it, it might be reasonable to leave them out.
On the other hand, it wouldn't be a good idea to use casual colloquialisms, with or without quotes, when they're not integral to the discussion, depending on the level of academic formality. For instance, in a scholarly work, I wouldn't write "By 18xx, Admiral Smith's colleagues generally saw him as having 'jumped the shark,' as it were." But I might if I were writing an opinion essay, or a piece aimed at making history accessible to a general audience, especially if Admiral Smith had had a famous encounter with a shark.
Finally, I should say that I've received advice in academic writing saying to avoid overusing "scare quotes." This is mostly a different matter, but related. The point of quote marks, in general, is to say "these are not my words." In your example, it means "I'm using the word 'wheelie,' but only because other people do; I don't own it as part of my own writing here." "Scare quotes" are similar, but might be applied to words or phrases that would be perfectly reasonable to use; instead, the author is distancing themself from their meaning. E.g. "Indigenous villages are being increasingly overrun by tourists seeking an 'authentic' experience." The author means that the tourists might describe it as "authentic," but it's such a notion is problematic and the author doesn't necessarily agree with it. General writing advice is to minimize the use of such scare quotes. To me, I don't think it's reasonable to eliminate them entirely, but they should probably be accompanied by explanation just like the colloquialisms. And a general principal for both kinds of quotes would be, use them if you need to, but if you find yourself using a lot, ask whether you really need to.
